# System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute and conditionally compiling supporting types and variables

Tags: c#

In a class, I've got a trace method that looks like this:

```
    [System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute("Trace")]
    private void TraceOutput(TraceBits bits, string format, params object[] varParams)
    {
        if ((bits & _DesiredTrace) != 0)
        {
           ...emit trace here...
        }
    }
```

TraceBits is a `[Flags] enum`.  Each call to TraceOutput passes in the bit that the call is tagged with.  Like this:

```
    TraceOutput(TraceBits.Fill,
                "Fill     lock     wi({0}) stat({1}) iba({2}) nf({3})",
                workitem.index,
                workitem.status,
                workitem.inputBytesAvailable,
                _nextToFill
                );
```

The bits are: Create, Read, Write, Fill, etc.   _DesiredTrace is a (private member variable) bitfield that indicates which trace statements should be actually emitted.  This way I can selectively turn on trace statements for various portions of function within the class. If I want to trace only construction and destruction, I set the Create bit in that member bitfield.

I can use the `ConditionalAttribute` on the method, but that attribute doesn't work on member variables or nested types (like TraceBits).

As a result, the types and variables that support tracing, are compiled into the code, whether or not `Trace` is defined.  If Trace is undefined then these are completely unnecessary.

Is there a clean way to conditionally compile the supporting types and variables in?

I know I can use `#if Trace ... #endif`  to surround the declaration and all invocations of TraceOutput, as well all the supporting stuff, but that uglifies the code.  I like the cleaner look of the `ConditionalAttribute`, where each call to TraceOutput does not need to be bracketed with `#if Trace`.

What I really want is some way to use that attribute, or something like it, on nested classes and member variables.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re the enum; the point about `[Conditional]` is that it is up to the **caller**'s build whether to actually perform the invoke - the *declaring/implementing* code is always included; so assume that your code is a standalone library; you *must* include the enum, otherwise the caller (assume the caller is separate) **cannot** possibly *ever* call the method.

It sounds like `#if` is a better fit for your problem - or you could use conditional inclusion in the build (csproj supports this, although it risks causing confusion; `#if` would be more obvious).

Note that to perform overload resolution it must first identify the types, so you can't really mix `#if` with `[Conditional]` since the enum is in the signature.